# SAPUI5: Not able to access items(or Elements) from Array(getting from List)

Tags: javascript, sapui5

**This code is from Controller.Here I am trying to get all items from the List(XML View)**

```js
onAfterRendering: function(oEvent) {

            var items = this.getView().byId("list").getItems("listitems");

            console.dir(items);




        }
```

**This code is from XMLview where populating List with Odata**

```
<List id="list"
            items="{ path: '/MYPROJECTSSet', sorter: { path: 'MpId', descending: false },groupHeaderFactory: '.createGroupHeader', parameters: { operationMode: 'Client' } }"
            busyIndicatorDelay="{masterView>/delay}" noDataText="{masterView>/noDataText}"
            mode="{= ${device>/system/phone} ? 'None' : 'SingleSelectMaster'}" growing="true" growingScrollToLoad="true"
            updateFinished="onUpdateFinished" selectionChange="onSelectionChange" >
            <infoToolbar>
                <Toolbar active="true" id="filterBar" visible="{masterView>/isFilterBarVisible}" press="onOpenViewSettings">
                    <Title id="filterBarLabel" text="{masterView>/filterBarLabel}"/>
                </Toolbar>
            </infoToolbar>
            <items>
                <ObjectListItem id="listitems" type="{= ${device>/system/phone} ? 'Active' : 'Inactive'}" press="onSelectionChange" title="{MpId}" intro="{Description}">
                    <firstStatus>
                        <ObjectStatus  id="icon" icon="{ parts: [ {path: 'ActualData'}, {path: 'PlannedData'} ], formatter : '.formatter.getIcon'}"/>
                    </firstStatus>
                </ObjectListItem>

            </items>
        </List>
```

**Below  is resulted Array i am getting in Console. i am not able to access elements of this Array using index**

is there any other way to get All items from the List ?
OR
other way to access array elements ?

[Click here to see resulted array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GaOXH.png)

Answer (score 0):

In your case you can get data as:

```
console.log(items[0].mProperties);
```

or:

```
var aData = (oList.getItems()).map(function(oItem){           
   console.log(oItem.getBindingContext().getObject());
});
```

The getBindingContext method expects a model name. Otherwise it will use default model. If one uses OData model with name, it should be passed to the getBindingContext method call.

[Here](http://jsbin.com/kopajemotu/1/edit?html,output) is simple demo, press button.

Comment: hey @Jaro, Thanks for the reply when I tried your first solution

**console.log(items[0].mProperties);**

it gave me following error
_Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'mProperties' of undefined_

and the second solution is not working either

Comment: Please, change this onAfterRendering: function(oEvent) { to onInit: function(oEvent) { and put my lines to this function.